# Show a Radio Button with only Text

Tags: asp.net, radio-button, label

I have two radio buttons in my page. I hide one of them in some scenarios. In that case the second radio button is selected by default. In that case alone I want to show it like a label as there is no meaning of showing it as a radio button. I am using asp radio button. How to achieve this. can there is a way to hide the option bubble in CSS for radio button.

Comment: can you update your question with ASPX code ?

Comment: No It is a big code. In abstract what i am asking is, is there a way to make a radio button to like a label on certain condition through css.

Comment: have a look at my answer. hope you will find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:  `$('#<%=this.RadioButton.ClientID%>').hide()`and 
`$('#<%=this.RadioButton.ClientID%>').show()`.

Answer (score 2):

considering this markup:

```
<asp:RadioButton ID="rbl" Text="value" CssClass="radio-toolbar" runat="server"/>
```

Then do this css style:

```
.radio-toolbar input[type="radio"] 
{
     display:none; 
}
```

this will only show the label of the `radiobutton`

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using JQuery. See below code sample. It will display only text :

```
<asp:RadioButton runat="server" Text="Radio 1" ID="radio1" />

<asp:Button runat="server" ID="buttonTest" OnClientClick="return ManageRadio();"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function ManageRadio() {
        $('#' + '<%=radio1.ClientID%>').hide();
        return false;
    }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

check the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKZ2k/2/) if you want to do it using css and js

i mean on binding click event.

--JQuery--

```
$(function(){
    $("#click_me").click(function(){
        $("#a").toggle(0,function(){
            $(this).next('label').toggle(0,function(e){
                $(this).next('input[type="radio"]').toggle();
            });
        });
    });
})
```

Check the [jfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nKZ2k/2/)